How do I know the quantity when purchasing?
Now I am using the in_app_purchase and in_app_purchase package in my app.
in_app_purchase: ^3.2.0
in_app_purchase_android: ^0.3.6+8
I want to purchase the multi instances in app.
But I can't find the method to get the quantity.
Please let me know how I can process this problem.
Screenshot
